# Windows equivalent to pause() syscall?

Tags: windows, assembly, system-calls

I would like to create a minimal Windows executable that does *nothing* - and is minimal in size.

All I care about is keeping a process entry in the task manager.

On Linux, this is very easy (it only takes 2 assembly instructions to use the `pause`
 syscall). How can I achieve similar results on Windows?

I'm trying to keep the executable size to a minimum, I don't want to have 10kB executable that literally does nothing.

Is there a way to achieve this in assembly? As I mentioned, I'd rather not include huge libraries just to make the process "hang".

Comment: `foo: jmp foo`?

Comment: @melpomene That's a busy wait. `pause()` is a system call the halts the process until a signal arrives.

Comment: `Sleep(INFINITE)` does not take a lot of code either.

Comment: Unfortunately, WinAPIs are, for a great deal, defined as user mode library functions. For example, `sleep` is a Kernel32 function using `ZwDelayExecution` (a.k.a. `NtDelayExecution`) that is implemented, on my system, as `mov r10, ... / mov eax, 31 / syscall`. The latter is the closest to the Linux counterpart, but it is not equivalent (being not portable). As Anders said in its answer, you can simply use any compiler to call `sleep` and rely on post build tools to strip down unused metadata and/or shrink the PE sections.

Comment: These kind of exercises are not especially worthwhile. In the real world, no one creates executables that do nothing, so the tools aren't optimized for it. No one cares about making do-nothing executables small, because no one cares about do-nothing executables. You include libraries because you need the functionality they provide many times over and they are more convenient to use than writing all the functions yourself. There are ways to write small executables that do something, of course, but it isn't worth the time writing an answer for one that does nothing. `pause` has its own problems.

Comment: Note that you can't portably make direct system calls the way you can on Linux. The system call numbers aren't officially documented and change with every version of Windows. You have to go through documented API functions if you want code that will work on a different version of Windows than the one you're using.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans suggests in the comments, `Sleep(INFINITE)` is probably the simplest non-busy wait. It does however mean you have to kill the process with Task Manager to stop it.

Calling `MessageBox` followed by `ExitProcess` is probably less annoying if you need to start/stop this process multiple times.

You can probably get it down to 1 KiB with Visual C++ if you don't use the CRT (`WinMainCRTStartup` and compile with `/Zl` and [smaller alignment](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/reducing-executable-size))

You can get it slightly smaller with assembly but it is probably not worth it.